# Understanding input in scheduled events in the serverless framework?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to pass some 'inputs' into my lambda function on a specific event and am researching ways of doing it. The serverless documentation shows examples of defining an input like [such](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cloudwatch-event#specify-input-or-inputpath):

*serverless.yml*

```
functions:
  aggregate:
    handler: statistics.handler
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(10 minutes)
          enabled: false
          input:
            key1: value1
            key2: value2
            stageParams:
              stage: dev
```

I am still unsure what exactly this is and how it can be accessed (if at all) from my handlers.js function.

If someone could de-mystify this, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These values will be passed to your lambda function as part of event object.

nodejs lambda code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) =>{
  console.log("key1 is", event.key1)
  return 0
}
```

Comment: does the name of the key has to be `key1`, I tried setting the key as `foo` but when I print the event object, the key `foo` is not present.

Comment: Is this in the AWS documentation somewhere? I can't find the corresponding handler in golang